# MySQL query counting keys from tree-like structure

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables:

```
 Department(ID,name) , 
 SubDepartment(parentID,childID) and 
 Department_Employees(idEmployee, idDepartment)
```

1. In table "Department_Employees" idDepartment is foreign key linked
   to ID of "Department" table.
2. In table "SubDepartment" parentID and childID are foreign keys both linked to  ID of "Department" table.

**One Department(parent)** can have many **SubDepartments(children)** and those **SubDepartments** can have their own **SubDepartments(children)** but **SubDepartment(child)** can't be parent of any of his parent Departments.
**"idEmployee"** is distinct in table **"Department_Employees" (Employee can belong to only one Department)**. These rules are covered from front-end side.

I have to count how many **employees ("idEmployee")** are in certain Department and ALL his SubDepartments. I also have to count how many SubDepartments are in certain Department including all children.

Lets say that I have something like this :

```
 1. MainDepartment(6 employees)



 - ITSector(3 employees)

    * Databases(4 employees)
    * Programmers(2 employees)


 - DeliverySector(4 employees)
```

I need the output to be MainDepartment has 4 subDepartments and 19 employees.

Is it  possible or advised to do this in one query with subqueries? I assume I need some kind of recursion for this but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: but the codes of department and Iddepartment overlaps? it could be an iddepartment =1 and and a childdepartment =1?

Comment: It does overlap but that case as well as loop case are sorted on front side. The reason why there are three tables instead of just linking Department on itself is that there is also field Date in SubDepartment table because I need to be able to track history of children switching parents.

Comment: I posted a solution, you have to insert a column name in you subdp table.  They could not overlap, how can distinguish the son of 1 who is his father?  You have to change something, may be put all in the same table and parentid=-1  for the main department. If overlaps the query below is gping to give wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested set model to store the hierarchical data. That means that your tables would be of form:
`Department(ID,name, parentID, left, right ) and Department_Employees(idEmployee, idDepartment)`.

```
    SELECT COUNT(parent.name), COUNT(employee.id)
FROM Department AS node ,
     Department AS parent,
     Department_employee AS employee
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.idDepartment = product.idDepartment
        AND parent.name = 'MAIN DEPARTMENT';
```

[More on Nested set representation for hierarchical data](http://Department(ID,name)%20,%20SubDepartment(parentID,childID)%20and%20Department_Employees(idEmployee,%20idDepartment))

Other option is keep the database structure the same. You can use a [sub queries](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-subquery.html) or a [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) to find the sub departments.

```
select count(id), count(distinct(idDepartment)) from Department_employee 
                   where idDepartment IN ( Getsubdepartment('Department') );
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive sounds like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dep (main_id,child_id,name) as
(SELECT d.id,d.id,d.name 
 FROM department d
 UNION ALL
 SELECT d.main_id, sd.child, d.name || '.' || sd.name
 FROM dep d INNER JOIN subdepartment sd on d.child_id=sd.parentid
)
SELECT s.name,count(idemployee) 
FROM dep d INNER JOIN dep s ON d.name LIKE s.name || '%'
LEFT JOIN department_employees de ON d.child_id=de.iddepartment
GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY s.name;
```

Tested on postgres it should work also in mysql.

It uses the path system for storage trees. It is very nice and easy. Left right does not apply very good with big and dinamic tree because at each insrt you have to update half db. If you make a copy paste of a branch you are going to update milions of records.